# PHP "foreach" in JavaScript with multidimensional array

Tags: php

I need to change a Chart dynamicly using JavaScript. The data for that chart is generated by a PHP script.

I am having some issues translating the following PHP `foreach` loop to javascript.

The PHP array is delivered to JS via

```
var MatchArray = <?php echo json_encode($match); ?>;
```

PHP loop (to JS):

```
foreach($match['timeline']['frames'] as $index => $row){

    foreach($row['events'] as $index2 => $row2){
        if ($row2['eventType'] == "CHANGE_MADE" && $row2['participantId'] == 1) {
            $a++;
        }
    }
    echo $a.",";
}
```

JS Chart data (generated by PHP script):

```
data : [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,13,13,13,14,15,15,16,16,16,17,18,18,18,]
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do with the foreach loop, it doesn't seem to indicate it's outputting anything or generating an array, so I don't see how it's relevant?

Comment: The `DoSomething()` function is just a placeholder. At this place, the script is processing the `$a` variable

Comment: OK, but what are you actually trying to do in the foreach loop? As far as I can see, the only productive action is to increment $a.

Comment: The PHP loop is outputting data to a JS script that is displaying a visual chart. `API -> PHP array -> JS chart` If `$a` gets increased by 1, the graph  goes up, etc.

Comment: Well, you're missing out code then if DoSomething() is only a placeholder. The only action that foreach loop performs is to increment $a by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = array();    
foreach($match['timeline']['frames'] as $index => $row){

        foreach($row['events'] as $index2 => $row2){
            if ($row2['eventType'] == "CHANGE_MADE" && $row2['participantId'] == 1) {
                $a++;
            }
        }
        $out[] = $a;
    }

echo json_encode($out);
```